# Override the parent url with child url in UI-router (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

This is the configuration i'm using for my ui-router:

```
.state('parent', {
    url: '/child1'
    controller: ParentController,
    abstract: true
})

.state('parent.child1', {
    url: ''
})

.state('parent.child2', {
    url: '/child2'
})
```

#### What I want to acheive ?

I want a /child1 url that I wanted to be default so I made the parent as abstract with child state url as 'empty'.

So I want that when user visits child2 state, the parent url gets replaced rather than appending it. How can i achieve that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you right, (please correct me if I'm wrong) you are looking to setup a routing service to achieve the following routes:

`/`, `/child1` and `/child2` and you want all states to be bound with `ParentController`

If that is correct you can achieve this with the following:

```
.state('parent', {
  url: '/',
  controller: ParentController,
})

.state('parent.child1', {
  url: '^/child1'
})

.state('parent.child2', {
  url: '^/child2'
})
```

For example if we were running `https://localhost:3000` we could navigate as such:

`parent` or `/` would give us `https://localhost:3000/`

`parent.child1` or `/child1` would give us `https://localhost:3000/child1`

`parent.child2` or `/child2` would give us `https://localhost:3000/child2`

The ParentController would be invoked by all states.

Comment: I did the same pattern before but I didn't want the '/' to be visited since it has to have a child.. So making that abstract along with your solution solved it for me.. Thanks.. :) Also didn't have to put `^` in child states

Comment: Ah excellent, yes I've had these issues before. UIRouter is so flexible that sometimes there's too many ways to achieve the same result. Glad to help.

Comment: Just a sidebar here: the `^` denotes an absolute path.  So if a person had two child states like: `parent.child.grandChild`, and used `^` the url would change from: `/parent/child/grandChild/` to `/grandChild/`